# Open mails in outlook from C# using the protocol “mapi://”

Tags: c#, mapi, wds

I wish to execute a URL in the format
`mapi://{S-1-5-21-1626573300-1364474481-487586288-1001}/toto@mycompany.com($b423dcd5)/0/Inbox/가가가가곕갘객겒갨겑곓걌게겻겨곹곒갓곅갩갤가갠가` , which I got from searching via Windows Desktop Search.

On Vista with Outlook 2007, this fails to open Emails if outlook is already open.  Except sometimes, when it works for mysterious reasons.

---

Below are some things I've tried in an attempt to get this to work:

Executing it with `Process.Start`, or executing it with `Process.Start` via cmd.exe /c start.  The former froze for a minute, then did nothing, with `Process.Start` returning null (except when Outlook was not already open, when it worked).  The latter popped up an "Unspecified Error" message box.

[Open mails in outlook from java using the protocol "mapi://"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400223/open-mails-in-outlook-from-java-using-the-protocol-mapi)
I couldn't figure out how to get this script to work.  The vbs scripts I generated claimed to have found invalid characters.  Also, this solution makes me sad.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsdesktopsearchdevelopment/thread/00491710-e245-452f-8b0a-56caa56277e4/
I suspect this solution will work.  However, I couldn't get it working in C++ or C# due to compiler errors.  This is a matter of not being sure which libraries to include or in C# how to effectively use `ShellItem2` etc. with interop.

[Creating application shortcut in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/how-do-you-create-an-application-shortcut-lnk-file-in-c-or-net)
I tried creating a shortcut and calling `Process.Start` on that.  This also did not work, though the shortcut itself worked when I double-clicked on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a UAC issue.  I tend to run VS as admin, since some apps need it.