# Open email using outlook mapi url

Tags: c#, outlook, windows-8.1, mapi

I queried the [windows search service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266517(v=vs.85).aspx) and got back a url in the System.ItemUrl property that reads something like this

```
mapi15://{S-1-5-21-1517436256-507059763-2860835189-1002}/...
```

Now I need to open that url in outlook. I tried Process.Start(url) in c#, but that popped out this message.

[image]

Is there a way to open mapi urls returned from windows search service? I am using windows 8.1 and outlook 2013. I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946701/open-mails-in-outlook-from-c-sharp-using-the-protocol-mapi) post, but that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400223/open-mails-in-outlook-from-java-using-the-protocol-mapi its in java but it should be relatively easy to conver to c#

Comment: This post describes a problem in java that doesn't use utf16. I am using c# which uses utf16 by default for strings. The error I get when running cmd /C "mapi://..." is 'mapi15:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this feature was [removed](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178954(v=office.15).aspx) in Office15. [This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ad382228-93bc-4ab0-a821-b428630b8204/search-outlook-2013-emails-using-start-menu-windows-search?forum=officeitpro) thread has some discussion on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change `mapi15` to `mapi` in the url:

```
mapi://{S-1-5-21-1517436256-507059763-2860835189-1002}/...
```